# Is there another +1 Charisma feat for a half-elf warlock who doesn’t want to be a "face"?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, content-identification

My half-elf warlock has 16 Charisma, and I’m considering taking the [Elven Accuracy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/elven-accuracy) feat (XGtE, p. 74), which would boost his Charisma to 17. Since I definitely want 20 Charisma eventually, a +2 Cha ASI and a second +1 Cha feat would get me there.

However, every other feat I can find that offers +1 to Charisma falls into one of three categories:

- Specific to some other race (e.g. [Dragon Fear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/dragon-fear) for dragonborn, from XGtE p. 74)
- Redundant for a warlock (i.e. [Resilient](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/resilient) choosing Charisma, from PHB p. 168)
- Related to being a “face” character (e.g. [Actor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/actor), from PHB p. 165)

Since I am a half-elf warlock, and I’m not really looking to be a face character, these options seem to run counter to the sort of character I’m trying to build. Are there any other options? Charisma for my warlock is all about “spirit” and magic.

Any Wizards of the Coast material, including *Unearthed Arcana*, might be considered here.

Comment: If your GM is sometimes open to Unearthed Arcana, do you think (s)he'd be open to other playtest material? (Like Wayfinders Guide to Eberron)

Comment: @DavidCoffron I don’t know per se, but *I* am interested in whatever material is available. I am not *only* interested in this particular warlock, but about knowing what options are out there in general for this kind of thing. I’m only restricting it to WotC material because vetting any other publisher and/or homebrew is beyond my ability at this point and would probably lead to the question being over-broad.

Comment: Are you strictly looking for feats, or would splitting your ASI into two +1s be off the table?

Comment: @JoelHarmon It might be what I actually *do*, but it would not be an answer to this question, no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The only feat option that is not a "face feat" are the dragonmarks.

Found in [Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/wgte), the Dragonmark feats are improvements on character creation options that allow for ability score increases that you desire.

The two that include half-elves are the Mark of Storm and the Mark of Detection. These let you choose the feat **Greater Dragonmark** which will give you an increase to either Charisma or Intelligence (for Detection) -or- Charisma or Dexterity (for Storm) as well as another small benefit related to the Dragonmark.

One thing to keep in mind, though, is that each of these options change your racial traits somewhat (although they both still offer +2 Charisma via your racial Ability Score Increase).

Comment: As you might have guessed, the +2 Charisma was the most important aspect of half-elf to me, making these rather attractive options. +1 certainly; might accept it later.

Answer (score 19):

Tasha's adds several new half-feats for charisma that aren't related to being a party face. In addition to the Dragonmarks covered by another answer, there are now the following options:

- Fey Touched: Learn Misty Step + a level 1 spell, cast each 1/day free
- Shadow Touched: Learn Invisibility + a level 1 spell, cast each 1/day free
- Skill Expert: 1 proficiency, expertise in one skill
- Telekinetic: Learn mage hand (or buff it if you have it)
- Telepathic: Gain telepathy (60 ft range)

All options can increase Charisma by 1

Comment: Great answer! I definitely would have strongly considered some of these for my character.

Answer (score 3):

## There are no official feats that provide what you're looking for

I've just searched through every feat for ability score or Charisma increases, and they are either ones you've already suggested, or ones that are Unearthed Arcana.

## However, Unearthed Arcana has some options.

You can look into these particular UA feats that all provide solutions to what you're looking for:

- Feats for Races UA

  - Everybody's Friend (Expertise on Persuasion/Deception)
- Feats for Skills UA

  - Silver-Tongued (Expertise on Deception, Deception for combat use)
  - Menacing (Expertise on Intimidate, Intimidate for combat use)

Every one of these options provide a +1 to Charisma.

There is another option that involves the Dragonmark feats which provides an ability score increase, but it requires a prerequisite feat to gain. It may be an option for later levels if that interests you.

Comment: @KRyan I'd really recommend Actor + the Disguise Self at will invocation.  You don't have to be a nice guy to use Actor, and the implications are *very* useful.

Comment: Fair! That’s a reasonable aside to include an otherwise-complete answer, and I will definitely consider it.

Comment: @KRyan While the Skill feats do provide expertise, the important thing is that they give means to disorient your enemies in combat, granting you advantage or frightening the target.

Comment: Sure, but it’s still a combat ability for a “face” character, even if it’s not necessarily being used to “face” at that particular moment. But that’s fine—I’m happier with more options (that I can strike out for my own purposes if I like) than less (leaving me unaware of other options).

Comment: The dragonmarks don't have prerequisite feats, but instead have Variant race requirements (which means it breaks the rules of the question)

Comment: @DavidCoffron Unless a *lot* has changed in Eberron, two of the dragonmarks are associated with half-elven houses (Lyrandar with the Mark of Storms, Medani with the Mark of Detection), so those seem like they would work? By “variant” do you just mean a sub-race (that might be OK)?

Comment: @KRyan It replaces your standard features with new ones (like the ones in SCAG do) using the rules in WGtE. I'm making an answer